# Identify this Bianchi - possibly 80s

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

Can someone please help me identify this Bianchi model?

My uncle has had it in storage for since years – I believe it's from the 80's.

Here are some photos, to help identify the model.

Cheers,
Alex

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Observation - the front wheel is Radially spoked.  That's quite unusual.